# Sub Category of Current Category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am currently using the code below in my category.php file to showe a list of the subcategories of the current category.

```
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . 
$term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

This is working fine for this application however I would like to amend it now to only show the next level down. Only the direct subcategories for the current category.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow Richard,
You can get direct child categories with below code

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$child_categories=  get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this I used <?php
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$child_categories=  get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);
 echo $child_categories;
?> And it just returns "array"

Comment: It is array and you can use it with for or foreach statement   for example  <?php foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $category_link = sprintf( 
            '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
            esc_html( $category->name )
        );
         
        echo $category_link . '<br/> ';
        echo $category->description . '<br/>';
        echo $category->count<br/>';
    }